# Two System Reserved Partitions after clean install on new drives

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, disk-management, system-reserved-partition

I just did a clean install of Windows 7 on a pair of SSDs (RAID 0) and was going to clear out my old HDD when I saw I have two system reserved partitions:

[image: Two System Reserved Partitions]

AFAIK I'm booting from Disk 1 (BIOS says it's using the SSD RAID), but when I go to delete the volume labeled D (the old system reserved partition), it says it's currently in use. However, right clicking the second system reserved doesn't present the option of deletion.

Is it safe to delete that partition? I'd like to format that entire disk into a single NTFS drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can remove it. And you're not able to delete one of them because it's mounted/in use. Use the setup disk to boot to a command prompt and use diskpart.

source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg441289.aspx

Comment: When I used diskpart from the setup disk and did list drives I only saw one, which matched the size of my smaller external. Do the drive numbers match up with what I see in disk management?